# Is it possible to fill out an InfoPath form via incoming email?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

Working on a solution for our SharePoint 2013 intranet site. We currently have a process by where new records are set up by our parent company, and they then email someone at our company the details of the new record. At that point, someone must manually fill out and submit an InfoPath 2013 form that I designed. The form is set as the template for a specific document library on a subsite, but we'd like to eliminate the duplication of work involved.

Ideally, the email from the parent company would include an email address for the document library and that would start the InfoPath part automagically. This would eliminate the extra step of someone starting the form manually after receiving the email. However, so far I can't figure out how to get the fields from the email into the form - only store the incoming email message.

I have access to the server farm, but I'm limited to SharePoint Designer workflows and/or whatever I can put into InfoPath 2013 client forms. At this point, a custom solution with event receivers or what-not isn't an option.

**Is it possible to fill out an InfoPath form and/or update a SharePoint list item using the content of an incoming email message?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Microsoft Support article about how to [Use InfoPath e-mail forms in Outlook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-infopath-e-mail-forms-in-outlook-113fe7c5-9dfe-4fa8-9c90-8780d5900a57)

The forms can be stored in a SharePoint document library and you may need to expose the IP fields as library columns in order to see them in a list view, or you will need 3rd party tools to extract the form data from the forms in the library.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, although it's not exactly what I'm after. Email forms allow you to use Outlook as the platform for filling out/updating forms. What I need to do is essentially send the email to a SharePoint library (i.e. - incoming email settings on the library), then create a new list item using the content of that email message.

Comment: So, how does that relate to InfoPath? No, you can't send an email to a SharePoint list and parse the email body content into a SharPoint list. Not out of the box. You will need custom code for that kind of stuff.